# fpdf caching for batching entryticket

Tags: php, caching, output, fpdf

I want create Tickets from SQL on the Server with fpdf (twpdf).
The problem is, all tickets has the data from the tickt before.

```
$pdfdoc = $twpdf->Output('./rechnung/Eintrittskarte_' . $arrDat['rechnungsnummer']."_".time().".pdf", "S");

header('Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
header("Cache-Control: private",false); // required for certain browsers 
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");   // any date in the past
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Length: '.strlen($pdfdoc));
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="doc.pdf"');
header('Pragma: public');
ini_set('zlib.output_compression','0');
```

The Ticket is in a attach from a email after 'output', and than the same with the next ticket.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking or what the problem is. Can you clarify further?